# Триггер в MySql не работает

Tags: mysql, sql, триггер

я новичок в MySql, написал такой код:

```
  CREATE TRIGGER add_error_history ON errors
  AFTER INSERT AS
  IF (SELECT error_status FROM errors ORDER BY error_id DESC LIMIT 1) = "Новая"
    INSERT INTO error_history VALUES(errors.error_user, "Ввод", CURDATE());
  ELSE
    BEGIN
    IF (SELECT error_status FROM errors ORDER BY error_id DESC LIMIT 1) = "Открытая"
      INSERT INTO error_history VALUES(errors.error_user, "Открытие", CURDATE());
    END;
```

Задача: 
Чтобы при добавлении в таблицу errors одного значения, в таблице error_history появлялась автоматически новая строка с измененными значениями.
Командная строка MySql ругается, в чем ошибка, ребят?

Comment: "Командная строка MySql ругается" - где текст ошибки?

Comment: Командная строка точно указывает, где и какая ошибка. Тут их хренова гора. Нет переопределения DELIMITER, нет BEGIN-END, вместо NEW используется сама таблица. Почитайте документацию, что ли... примеры там посмотрите...

Answer (score 0):

Написал вот так:

```
    DELIMITER // 

CREATE TRIGGER add_error_history AFTER INSERT ON errors
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  IF (NEW.error_status = "Новая") THEN
      INSERT INTO error_history VALUES(NEW.error_user, "Ввод", CURDATE());
    END IF;
  IF (NEW.error_status = "Открытая") THEN
      INSERT INTO error_history VALUES(NEW.error_user, "Открытие", CURDATE());
    END IF;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```